# Terminal only outputs last few lines and everything before is deleted

Tags: command-line, grep, search, output, lxterminal

I am using `grep` to find strings in multiple files. It outputs a lot of text which is what I need, but then terminal just deletes all the output while `grep` continues working and so I can see only last few results `grep` found.

How do I make `grep` work?

I am sorry for noob question but I literally searched whole internet and didn't find answer. What I need is to search for text in multiply binary files recursively and output line from those binary files containing searched text.

`grep` does that but I can't use it, if there is another app that can do that it would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output to a pager like `less`, or redirect it to a file, and then read the file using your favorite editor or pager.

For example:

```
grep -R foo ./DIR | less    # search for foo, view a screen full at a time
```

or:

```
grep -R foo ./DIR > outputs # search for foo, and output the results to a file

less outputs                # view the file one screen full at a time
```

Comment: how do you use second method? I tried ' > outputs' and ' | less > output.txt' but it does not do anything.

Comment: First use `grep whatever > outputs` it saves data to a file named outputs then with another command read outputs data for example `less outputs`

Comment: @Ravexina in your example, it won't find "Foo". You might wish to add -i to your grep, as without it, grep is case sensitive.

Comment: @heynnema it's just a demonstration ... I'm sure he/she knows how to work with grep already.

Comment: @Ravexina I don't think so, as the OP says "I am sorry for noob question...".